# viewbag returning null in view and not in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
    ViewBag.jsscript = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('d');</script>";
    return Redirect(refUri + "#/newFile");
```

In controller it is fine assigning the value

view

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.jsscript)
```

But in view it is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewBag` can only be used to provide values from Controller to View in the same request. When you use 'Redirect(...)' there is another request coming from the browser, so your `ViewBag` value does not exist in that next request.

You can use 'TempData' to store data that survives one request. I'm not sure if you can use it in your code because it is hard to tell the full scope from just a few lines that you provided, but you can try that.

Comment: ok.. is there any way to pass update the viewbag data of othercontroller from the same ...

Comment: You could try to use your own MyViewBag class that stores important data you want to send between controllers and views, for instance `class MyViewBag<T> { public T GeneralItem { get; set; } }` etc. Probably not the best way of solving problem but could help temporarly :)